# change searchoptions in jqgrid toolbar filter with setColProp

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid 4.4.5 and the toolbar filter.The grid can reloads base on condition(for example inbox or outbox letters).I use select options of a column.I need to change the select options of a 'type' column.For example if the grid show 'inbox letter' Then 'select options'  show 'A,B' Otherwise show 'C,D'.
I use this code for create grid:

```
function creatGrid() {

var inboxSearchOptions = 'A:A;B:B;All:';//inbox Options
var inboxEditOptions = 'A:A;B:B';

var outboxSearchOptions = 'C:C;D:D;ALL:';
var outboxEditOptions = 'C:C;D:D';

grid.jqGrid({
    url: 'jqGridHandler.ashx',
    datatype: 'json',
    width: 100,
    height: 200,
    colNames: ['Email', 'Subject', 'Type', 'ID'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Email', width: 100, sortable: false, },
        { name: 'Subject', width: 100, sortable: false, },
        {
            name: 'Type',
            width: 100,
            search: true,
            formatter: 'select',
            edittype: 'select',
            editoptions: { value: (($.cookie("calledFrom") == "inbox") ? inboxEditOptions : outboxEditOptions), defaultValue: 'ALL' },
            stype: 'select',
            searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: (($.cookie("calledFrom") == "inbox") ? inboxSearchOptions : outboxSearchOptions) },
        },
        { name: 'ID', width: 100, sortable: false, hidden: true, key: true },
    ],
    rowNum: 20,
    loadonce: true,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    recordpos: "left",
    ignoreCase: true,
    toppager: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    multiselect: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    scrollOffset: 1,
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    multiboxonly: true,
    jsonReader:
    {
        repeatitems: false,
    },
    gridview: true,
}
```

}

Then i use this code for reload grid:

```
function doReloadMainGrid() {

switch (($.cookie("calledFrom")) ) {
case "inbox":
    {
        window.grid.setColProp("Type", {
            searchoptions: {
                value: inboxSearchOptions,
            },
            editoptions: {
                value: inboxEditOptions
            },                    
        });
    }
    break;
case "outbox":
    window.grid.setColProp("Type", {
        searchoptions: {
            value: outboxSearchOptions,
        },
        editoptions: {
            value: outboxEditOptions
        },                    
    });
    break;
}

var url = createUrl();
window.grid.setGridParam({ datatype: 'json' });
window.grid.setGridParam({ url: url });
window.grid.trigger("reloadGrid", { current: true });
```

}

But the 'setColProp' has no effect.I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743745/reload-searchoptions-in-jqgrid-with-setcolprop) but it was not a good solution for me.What i got wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setColProp` don't change **existing** filter toolbar. If you just get the values from cookie or `localStorage` than it would be better to do this **before** the filter toolbar will be created by `filterToolbar` method.

You can use `destroyFilterToolbar` to **recreate** the filter toolbar using new values in `colModel`. If you have to use old version of jqGrid you can just follow [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13700184/315935) which describe how to add the code `destroyFilterToolbar` to old version of jqGrid.